# How to get this scaling boxes image and text in proportion when you resize the window to any size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/37aMB/15/

If you resize the area at some points image will have have space at bottom and some time right side container will have space at bottom.

I want to make everything in proportion and with equality. Red backgeound should never be seen

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set fixed size for this banner, and then manipulate `zoom` style attribute.
[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/37aMB/19/show/) is modified example. It's not pixel perfect yet, but I have the impression it scales better.